# Proper way of using CLLocationManager (to start/stop updating user location)

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have a `UIView` with an `MKMapView`, in a UIViewController, which appears only when user taps a button.

The process is as follows:

- A `CLLocationManager` object is declared as private member in the `header` file.
- A `UIView` with an `MKMapView` is presented (initially the frame is outside bounds. Is moved to within view bounds on user's action, WITHIN THE SAME `viewController`).
- It is initialized:

  ```
  locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]  init];
  locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
  locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest; // 100 m
  [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
  CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];

  MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.04, 0.04);
  MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span);
  mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
  [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
  ```
- Nearby locations are fetched using `Foursquare API`

Now, I wish to stop the location lock, when the `view` is removed from visible bounds.
I tried it with `stopUdatingUserLocation`. I also `released` the `locationManager`, but the GPS lock icon is persistent in the `statusBar`. As I understand, continuous GPS lock drains the battery, and I would like to stop that. How would I go about it ?

Comment: Even tho it's not officially documented, it would be better to use only one CLLocationManager throughout your whole app. Treat it as a singleton, don't initialise it every time, and it should work properly.

Comment: iOS 7 still has a leak regarding MKMapView. Maybe you should try your solution on iOS 6 to verify?

Comment: @Klaas, I have not migrated to iOS7/XCode5 yet. I'm working with iOS-6.1.

Comment: @micantox, for some reason, your idea seems to work. You should post this as an answer, and i will accept it.

Comment: I did, and I do think that it's something that apple should manage better than that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even tho it's not officially documented, it would be better to use only one CLLocationManager throughout your whole app. Treat it as a singleton, don't initialise it every time, and it should work properly.