# MKMapView sometimes zoomz to user location sometimes zooms to middle of nowhere

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mkcoordinateregion

I am using am mapview and sometimes my map will zoom onto my users location when I open it but sometimes it will zoom to the middle of an ocean. I don't know what is causing this, this is the code I am using for zooming. I don't want the map to track the user but just zoom to their location once they open the map

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.mapView.userLocation.coordinate, 600.0f, 600.0f);
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

 }

 -(void) viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];

self.mapView.delegate = self;
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this issue before. It seems that mapView is slow to load and detect user location sometimes, resulting in your code in `viewDidAppear` being executed *before* the map view can check user's location. Thus, the spot in the ocean.

It will be better to use mapView's delegate to display user location when it's ready:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    if(isShowUserLocation)
    {
        MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 600.0, 600.0);
        [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];
        isShowUserLocation = NO;
    }
}
```

Set `isShowUserLocation = YES` in `viewDidLoad`. This ensures the user location is shown once on entry and also selectively when you need it.

**Edit 1:**

```
@implementation MapViewController
{
    BOOL isShowUserLocation;
}

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate = self;
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
    isShowUserLocation = YES;
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Alternatively, use CLLocationManager - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918019/proper-way-of-using-cllocationmanager-to-start-stop-updating-user-location). It allows you stop the updating. Do include CoreLocation.framework. You may need to handle some nitty-gritty issues when interacting CLLocationManager with MapView though.

Comment: the problem with this solution is that I want to show the users location on the map so if I set showsUserLocation = NO then it won't pop up. But, if I leave it on then the gps will keep updating the userlocation and re-adjusting my maps location when I don't want it to. Is there a way to make sure userLocation is set without using this method?

Comment: That's why I used isShowUserLocation (a BOOL variable I created, not mapView's showsUserLocation property) to control the update. It works around the problem you just described. I suggest you try it out and see the result for yourself.

Comment: Thanks this works, the only question I have is would this increase battery life since now you are constantly using the gps and calling the didupdateUserLocation?

Comment: I believe it's negligible when compared to mapView's operations which use more power when updating its map during panning, zooming, etc. My own observations: user location can be updated with GPRS but updating map requires at least 3G enabled. You have to test it to see if it meets your design criteria.

Answer (score 2):

When  you pass 0's for lat and long, you will git a spot in the middle of the ocean south of Ghana in Africa.

Comment: So how do I guarantee that I get the mapview generates the users location before I zoom to the region?